# Is there any way to determine whether an update to a database row was performed by a web application (php process), or run by hand through a DB GUI

Tags: php, mysql

I need to allow edits made via a DB GUI though to my auditing system so that they are also being tracked. I am updating the audit table using a BEFORE trigger, and i would like to be able to alter the audit row to indicate what the source of the update was (via an existing 'modified_by' column).

I cannot add an additional column to the audit table for this because I want to be able to copy from the updated table to the audit table without specifying table columns like below (I don't want this trigger to require that I update it with changes to the schema).

MY TRIGGER:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO contacts_audit SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = NEW.id;
END
```

PSEUDO TRIGGER:

```
BEGIN
    IF(GUI EDIT) THEN
        SET NEW.modified_by_id = 1; /* 1 is the administrator id */ 
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO contacts_audit SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = NEW.id; 
END
```

Comment: Maybe you can add code to your application to set a variable when starting a connection and checking for that in the trigger?

Comment: It's not database's job to worry **what** updated it. Unless you can pass some information via query to determine *what* is performing the query, then no, you can't.

Comment: By setting a variable I meant doing this with SET syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "DB GUI" connecting to the database is a client, a php connection is a client too, the same as any other way to connect to the database, so there is no flag like "this is php".

You can however use the USER() or SESSION_USER()-function in the trigger to get the active user/hostname of the current connection, so just use a different user/host for php and the gui if you want to seperate them.

Comment: This solution works for me. Gui edits are done with the root user, and the app connected as another user with restricted permissions. So I can use the USER() to determine what to do in the trigger. Thanks.